# Github.com repos created not showing on Github desktop

Tags: github

New to git and github. Not sure why the repos created on my github.com page do not show on the github desktop version. Aren'they supposed to be automatically synced?

Comment: GitHub Desktop does not automatically download the repositories. We have to clone the repository manually. You can find the solution for this issue on their official git repo here. https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/5161.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In GitHub Desktop, select `File > Clone repository`, or use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>.

There, under the "GitHub.com" tab, you can see the list of all GitHub repositories that you have access to. You can click on the refresh icon to re-sync if any repository is not yet visible.